# How to use combineLatest for two public subjects in RXSwfit

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I'm new to RXSwift and I try to use combineLatest to combine the latest results from two public subjects

What I tried to do:

```
let sub1 = PublicSubject<Type1>()
let sub2 = PublicSubject<Type2>()

NetworkService1.fetch { sub1Value in 
   sub1.onNext(sub1Value)
}

NetworkService2.fetch { sub21Value in 
   sub2.onNext(sub2Value)
}

Observable.combineLatest(sub1.asObservable(), sub2.asObservable()) {
   val1, val2 in 
   // do something with val1 and val2
   // It seems it never hits this block
}
```

Not sure I'm doing the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's better, if your `NetworkService` returns `Observables`. Then you don't have to create `PublicSubjects` and it's more beautiful.

I would do it like this:

```
let result1 = NetworkService1.shared.fetch()
let result2 = NetworkService2.shared.fetch()
Observable.combineLatest(result1, result2) { r1, r2 in
    // Do stuff with r1, r2 with are APIResult<[YourModel]> and return result
}.subscribe(onNext: { result in
    // You need to subscribe to run fetch methods
    // Do stuff with result of combine latest
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

This is example of a fetch method using `Alamofire` that returns `Observable`:

```
func fetch() -> Observable<APIResult<[YourModel]>> {

    return Observable<APIResult<[YourModel]>>.create { (observer) -> Disposable in

        Alamofire.request(yourURLString,
                          method: .post,
                          parameters: nil,
                          headers: APIManager.headers())
            .responseJSON(completionHandler: { dataResponse in

                switch dataResponse.result {
                case .success(let value):

                    // parse value to someArray here
                    observer.onNext(APIResult.success(someArray))

                case .failure(_):
                    guard let code = dataResponse.response?.statusCode else {
                        observer.onNext(APIResult.failure(APIError.unknownError))
                        break
                    }
                    observer.onNext(APIResult.failure(APIError.networkError(code:code)))
                }

                observer.onCompleted()

            })

        return Disposables.create()
    }

}
```

`APIResult` allows you to pass errors too:

```
enum APIResult<Value> {
    case success(Value)
    case failure(APIError)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just a couple of observations first:

1. There is no `PublicSubject`, it's `PublishSubject` (probably just a typo ;)
2. You don't need to call `asObservable()` in order to use PublishSubjects as arguments for `combineLatest`
3. You have to subscribe to your Observable (in this case `Observable.combineLatest`), otherwise nothing will happen.
4. Even if you subscribe correctly to `Observable.combineLatest`, you won't get the values, that have been emitted before the subscription, so those fetch calls have to be triggered after the subscription.

Since a piece of code is worth a thousand words:

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
let sub1 = PublishSubject<String>()
let sub2 = PublishSubject<String>()

Observable.combineLatest(sub1, sub2) {
  val1, val2 in
  // do something with val1 and val2
  // IT SHOULD WORK NOW
}.subscribe().disposed(by: disposeBag)

NetworkService1.fetch { sub1Value in 
  sub1.onNext(sub1Value)
}

NetworkService2.fetch { sub2Value in 
  sub2.onNext(sub2Value)
}
```